# Second order differential equation with unknown coefficient numerically

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

I have the following differential equation
$$x''(t)+p(t) x'(t)=0,\qquad t\in[0,1]$$
I need to solve it numerically (find $x(t_i)$, where $\displaystyle t_i=\frac{i}{N}$ for $i=1,...,N-1$) using next conditions:
$$x(0)=0$$
$$x(t_1)=a,(a<1)$$
$$x(t_{N-1})=1-b, (b < 1-a)$$
$$x(1)=1$$
The problem is the function $p(t)$ is unknown. We know only that $p(t)$ "is required to satisfy the Neumann boundary condition. It is computed by an iterative optimization process loop".

I'm not good enough at this part of mathematics. I would be grateful, if someone could help me, give a clue, basic idea.